# Rundeck monitor directory

Tags: rundeck

Does anyone know if Rundeck has the functionality to trigger a job upon the arrival of a file in a directory?

I've searched a bit, and it doesn't seem like I've found this feature, either in the enterprise version or in the community version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an appropriate circumstance for the [Waitfor Rundeck Nixy Plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/nixy-step-plugins).

You may install it by going to the gear icon > plugins > locate plugins > in the "search for..." area, type "nixy" and then install the "*nixy waitfor Steps" plugin.

Now, in your workflow, you add a step to validate that, called "*nixy / waitfor / file-exist". You can provide the file path, the wait interval in seconds, and the maximum number of tries.

Check this job definition example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 447af8f3-fc99-4bda-bc2d-aa91ee9c5233
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ProjectEXAMPLE
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - configuration:
        file: /home/user/Downloads/myfile
        interval: '60'
        maxtry: '2'
      nodeStep: true
      type: nixy-waitfor-file-exists
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 447af8f3-fc99-4bda-bc2d-aa91ee9c5233
```

This job waits 60 seconds for the "myfile" file on the `/home/user/Downloads/` directory, if the file isn't there, it tries twice.

Alternatively, you can put a bash script logic in a script step job like this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the directory to monitor
directory_to_monitor="/home/user/Downloads"

# Function to monitor the directory for new files
monitor_directory() {
    # Initial list of files in the directory
    initial_files=$(ls "$directory_to_monitor")

    while true; do
        # List files in the directory
        current_files=$(ls "$directory_to_monitor")

        # Check for new files
        new_files=$(comm -13 <(echo "$initial_files") <(echo "$current_files"))

        # If new files are detected, print a message and exit
        if [ -n "$new_files" ]; then
            echo "New file detected: $new_files"
            exit 0
        fi

        # Sleep for a while before checking again
        sleep 5
    done
}

# Call the function to monitor the directory
monitor_directory
```

Now, the script working in a Rundeck job (the directory path is defined in an Rundeck Option).

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 685e175b-6554-402e-a511-7a0af8420bd7
  loglevel: INFO
  name: Check Directory
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: directory
    required: true
    value: /home/user/Downloads/
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - configuration:
        adhocLocalString: |-
          #!/bin/bash

          # Define the directory to monitor
          directory_to_monitor=@option.directory@

          # Function to monitor the directory for new files
          monitor_directory() {
              # Initial list of files in the directory
              initial_files=$(ls "$directory_to_monitor")

              while true; do
                  # List files in the directory
                  current_files=$(ls "$directory_to_monitor")

                  # Check for new files
                  new_files=$(comm -13 <(echo "$initial_files") <(echo "$current_files"))

                  # If new files are detected, print a message and exit
                  if [ -n "$new_files" ]; then
                      echo "New file detected: $new_files"
                      exit 0
                  fi

                  # Sleep for a while before checking again
                  sleep 5
              done
          }

          # Call the function to monitor the directory
          monitor_directory
        interpreterArgsQuoted: 'false'
      nodeStep: true
      type: script-inline
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 685e175b-6554-402e-a511-7a0af8420bd7
```